# find an empty value gap in a list and allocate a group of strings

Tags: python

I am new in Python and I am looking for an elegant way to do this:

```
list0 = ["text1","text2","","","text3","","text4","text5","","text6"]
```

I want to group together the non-empty strings that are detected after the gap in indices 2 and 3, and allocate this group starting at a specific index (e.g. index 5). The new list should look like *list1*. (To see *list1*) [click here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPXz3.png)

Comment: why does your result list have the empty string as its last element?

Comment: can you explain what you need more concrete?

Comment: So do you want to sort the tail of the list after the first gap so that on-empty entries come before empty entries? That's not hard to do, but wanting to do it on only a part of the list is really weird, and needlessly complicates the question. Why would you need to do this; which problem are you attempting to solve this way?

Comment: @tripleee that can't be it, otherwise the result would not end with the empty string.

Comment: I'm confused on the definition of a "gap". Two consecutive empty strings?

Comment: @cricket_007 , me too. I was thinking he can just overload the sort function such that empty strings are given a lower priority but I wonder what the OP is asking for

Comment: yes, gap is a the two consecutive empty strings. Also, this could be just one empty value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description of the question, this seems to be what you want, but I'm unsure why there is an empty string at the end of your sample output.

Also, this directly modifies `list0` , so feel free to change the references to `list1` if you wish.

```
list0 = ["text","text","","","text","","text","text","","text"]

# Find the "gap" - the first consectutive empty strings
# gap_pos remains 0 if no gap is found
gap_pos = 0
gap_size = 2
for i in range(len(list0)-gap_size):
    if all(x == '' for x in  list0[i:i+gap_size]):
        gap_pos = i+1
        break # remove this if you want the last gap

# Find the non-empty strings that are detected after the gap
after_gap = filter(lambda x : x != '', list0[gap_pos+1:])

# allocate this group starting at a specific index (e.g. index 5)
specific_index = 5
for i in range(len(after_gap)):
    allocate_at = i + specific_index
    # Make sure not to go out-of-bounds
    if allocate_at < len(list0):
        list0[allocate_at] = after_gap[i]
```

**Outputs**

```
['text', 'text', '', '', 'text', 'text', 'text', 'text', 'text', 'text']
```

Comment: The empty string at the end is worthless.

Comment: Not actually as you predefined the length of gap as 2. The goal is to find any gap (i.e. >= 1) and the sort the tail at a specific index.

Comment: The number of non-empty strings should remain the same. What I am looking is to clean a csv file, by grouping the two blocks without intermediate gaps; the first, which is anything until the first empty string and the second, all the remaining ones. The second block should start at index 5.

Comment: Please add your image to your question instead of my answer where only I will be notified about it

Answer (score 1):

well, I am not sure if this answers your post

```
import Queue
list0 = ["text","text","","","text","","text","text","","text"]
queue = Queue.Queue()
count = 0
for i, val in enumerate(list0):
    if  val == "":
       count += 1
    else:
       if count > 1:
           queue.put(i)
       count = 0

index = 5
queue.put(len(list0))
while queue.qsize() > 1:
    begin = queue.get()
    tmp = filter(lambda a: a != "", list0[begin:queue.queue[0]])
    list0[begin:queue.queue[0]] = [""] * (queue.queue[0]-begin)
    list0[index:index+len(tmp)] = tmp
```

I just scan through the list and sort them by block between gaps

```
['text', 'text', '', '', '', 'text', 'text', 'text', 'text', '']
```

Well, I am wondering if I am right.

Comment: All looks good except that the second block should start at a specific index, e.g. index 5.

Comment: so the indents are hardcoded?

Please list your specifications better. Some of us just try to solve whatever is presented than intended. some things seems arbitary depending on input data

Comment: Was already at the description: _starting at a specific index (e.g. index 5)_

Answer (score 0):

If it's missing anything tell me

```
list0 = ["text","text","","","text","","text","text","","text"]
    list1 = list0[:]
    counter= 0
    for i in range(0,len(list0)):
        if(list0[i]=="" and counter < 2 ):
            counter= counter + 1

        elif(counter >= 2):
            list1[i] = "text"

        elif(counter < 2):
            list1[i] = list0[i]
```

Comment: It seems to be "messing" more than the OP's original solution.

Comment: can you explain a litle more? for I improve my answer our you improve?

Comment: Not sure if this is "an elegant way"